# Difference between Risk Transfer and Risk Sharing

Tags: risk, risk-management

There seems to be a thin line between risk transfer and risk sharing. Can someone explain with example how can this be differentiated?

Answer (score 3):

**Risk Transfer** simply involves transferring "**only**" risk to another person for a price. For example, the downside risk of stock can be transferred by purchasing a call option. In this way, the buyer of call option transfers its risk to the writer of the call option. Another example is **insurance**, wherein, the buyer of insurance transfers its risk to an insurance company.

**Risk Sharing** is an entirely different concept. It involves sharing (dividing) common risk among two or more persons. I think the  **"partnership"** form of business organization is the most common (and oldest) practice of risk sharing. Banks also use this practice to lend a big amount to individual large size corporation, each bank supplying a portion of the loaned funds. In these cases "**both**" the profits, as well as potential losses, are shared between the parties.